# CASE statement with multiple THEN's

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I am using the following SQL to try and accomodate multiple scenarios for an input parameter.

```
AND ec.eventId in (CASE WHEN @event = 'test_reeq' THEN 223
                        WHEN @event = 'test_NT' THEN 224
                        WHEN @event = 'Both' then '223,224'
                        WHEN @event = 'All' THEN ec.EventId
                        end
                        )
```

My trouble appears to be with my attempt to use the 'both' input. SQL does not like the comma, and I've tried using parentheses instead of single quotes, as well as no quotes, but still no luck. Is it even possible to do what I'm trying to do?

For a bit more info: The EventId itself is an integer data type in the DB. For sake of convenience for user (this will ultimately be an SSRS report), I'd like to have the option for having these two ID's (223,224) grouped by using the keyword 'Both'. I am aware that in SSRS, I could just do a multi-select and even maybe have those two selected by default, but I'd prefer to have them grouped together as an option.

Comment: Does `'Both'` mean that `eventId` has to be _both_ 223 and 224? I don't think that's possible. Perhaps the option name should be `'Either'`? Maybe you could show some sample data, and identify which rows would be returned when `Both` or `All Others` are selected.

Comment: It just doesn't work that way. Search the internet for "case in where" and you will find many examples and discussions. And note that 'All Others' actually means (as you have coded it) EVERYTHING - there is no "other" implied in that logic. If that was what you desired, then your logic needs to be changed.

Comment: 'Both' should be 223 AND 224, and 'All Others' is not suitably named, it should be just 'All', which I understand is everything including 223 and 224.

Comment: Can you show a single row in your table where `eventId` is both 223 _and_ 224? Or, again, does it really mean _either_ 223 _or_ 224?

Comment: Sorry: you got me on that, I did mean either. I wasn't thinking with SQL syntax in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use another `CASE` expression as

```
DECLARE @Var VARCHAR(45) = 'Both';
-- You can change the value of the varible @Var to test for other inputs
SELECT *
FROM
(
  VALUES
  (223),
  (224),
  (1)
) T(Col)
WHERE Col IN (
               CASE @Var
                 WHEN 'test_reeq' THEN 223
                 WHEN 'test_NT' THEN 224
                 WHEN 'Both' THEN 223
                 WHEN 'All Others' THEN Col
               END
             ) OR Col = CASE WHEN @Var = 'Both' THEN 224 END;
```

You can get ride of `IN()` and use

```
WHERE Col = CASE @Var
                 WHEN 'test_reeq' THEN 223
                 WHEN 'test_NT' THEN 224
                 WHEN 'Both' THEN 223
                 WHEN 'All Others' THEN Col
               END
              OR Col = CASE WHEN @Var = 'Both' THEN 224 END;
```

<kbd>[`Online Demo`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=65552902c12c1fa230213dcfebed8f52)</kbd>